# Weekly Cron Job

Tags: linux, cron

I want to create Cron job that will run evey 2 weeks on Sunday , I tried this but get Error bad day of week

```
47 15 * * SUN/2 export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/java -jar /home/ahmed/Projects/DimensionProject/ProviderJar/FtpDownload.jar  LightningSource /home/ahmed/NetBeansProjects/trunk/BookDimensionProject/build/web/linconfig.xml
```

so any one can help please??

Answer (score 0):

We could use `date +%s` to obtain the number of seconds since the Epoch, convert that to weeks (604800 seconds = 1 week), and run the cron job only on odd weeks:

```
47 15 * * SUN    test $(expr $(date +%s) / 604800 % 2) -eq 1 && echo "Every other Sunday"
```